# Efficient substring matching on enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum like so

```
public enum Colors
{
    Green,
    LightGreen,
    Blue
}
```

and given a string

```
string substringToMatch = "Green"
```

I'd like to be able to retrieve all elements in my enum that contain my string as a substring efficiently - ideally even type-insensitive.

So far I've been able to find exact matches with `Enum.TryParse`, but haven't found a way to do substring matching as well.

Comment: Define "efficiently". Unless you're going to use some kind of dedicated string data structure, all such searches will at least need to go through all members of the enum. Then again, if you have an enum with very many members you're probably doing it wrong anyway, likewise if this operation is somehow a bottleneck in your process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Colors> matchingColors = Enum.GetValues<Colors>()
    .Where(c => c.ToString().Contains(substringToMatch, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KmsyvP

Edit: for .NET framework you have to change 2 things, no generic `Enum.GetValues` and no `String.Contains` with `StringComparison` overload. So you can use:

```
IEnumerable<Colors> matchingColors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Colors)).Cast<Colors>()
    .Where(c => c.ToString().IndexOf(substringToMatch, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Comment: I wouldn't say this is "efficient" though. Cache the enum strings and it would be better.

Comment: @DavidG: is this something you know based on benchmarks or is it a gut feeling? Those strings are basically member names, which the runtime can cache just as well. Adding your own caching may pessimize things. (As an aside, `Enum.GetName()` is an alternative to `.ToString()`, though I have no idea about relative performance.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert: `Enum.GetName` is used in `ToString`, basically. But i agree, don't add caching if you don't have to. That adds complexity without reason. The substring search is what costs most and you can't optimize that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Sure, how's this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Paruz.png

Comment: @DavidG: that just raises more questions, since neither the benchmark code nor the runtime version(s) are included. But I don't want to start a whole discussion about how to micro-optimize this, because that will probably lead to a completely different implementation that uses dedicated string-matching algorithms for the substring search, never mind any caching. Let's settle for "the OP should profile/benchmark their particular use case".

Comment: I just noticed that this doesn't work for .NET 4.8, because there wasn't a `GetValues<TEnum>()` function back then. You don't happen to have a solution that would work with .NET 4.8?

Comment: @emilaz: for .NET framework use `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Colors)).Cast<Colors>()` . I haveedited my answer